# Spring Zuul Gateway - with Spring Cache Redis

Tags: java, spring, netflix-zuul

Is it possible to have a Spring Zuul Gateway Project , which can have caching on the gateway itself , so before it routes to any microservices , it checks for the same request on a REDIS Server and return the cache data if it finds an entry on the REDIS Server ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it with zuul. But also you can use out of the box nginx with [reverse-proxy caching](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/reverseproxycachingexample/). It coul me faster and easier.